# 11.10 Fresh install , no visual effects

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz, graphics

I just installed 11.10. The menu bar and windows don't have drop shadows, and the menu bar is still visible/opaque when I click on the dash home button. My graphics card is a GeForce FX5950 ultra. Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are in **Ubuntu 2D**. You want **Ubuntu** (aka Unity 3D). First, check that you are signed in to 'Ubuntu' at the login screen:

[image: login]

Failing that, make sure you have the latest NVIDIA drivers installed. Go to your System Settings (click the gear icon at the very top right of the screen), and select 'Additional Drivers'.

[image: system settings screen]

Choose the default selection, labeled 'version-current' like below:

[image: NVIDIA driver selection]

If this doesn't fix it after logging out and logging back in, check that your card is capable of supporting Unity's 3D effects:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

[image: graphics test]

Answer (score 0):

System Settings -> (under Hardware section) Additional Drivers -> Choose whichever driver best suits you.
When logging in, choose Ubuntu session.

Comment: I have NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver version 173. What is Unity 2d and why should I use it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Ubuntu session. So you had graphics card installed already? Then we might want to focus on CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm). If you don't have it, you can simply get it via Ubuntu Software Center. To get shadows, you need to enable Window Decoration option in Effects section (for your comfort, edit the options inside for shadows). As for the menu bar, I don't fully understand the problem, can you post a screenshot with indication of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If Additional Drivers don't show you anything, go to the nvidia drivers section, and download the driver. [Here](http://uk.geforce.com/drivers/results/35493)